# Why these two cases gives the same results?

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion

I was following the tutorial here:
http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/110/BinaryTrees.html

The very first problem is to construct the following binary tree:

```
 2
 |  \
 1   3
```

My question is, why the following two main functions gives the same result. From what I understand, in the second case after the second call to the insert function, root will point to the child i.e. the node containing 1 and therefore it should create a tree which looks like

```
2
|
1
|
3


int main(void){
  struct node* root = NULL;
  struct node* n1;
  struct node* n2;
  root = insert(root, 2);
  n1 = insert(root, 1);
  n2 = insert(root, 3);
  print(root);
  return SUCCESS;
}



int main(void){
  struct node* root = NULL;
  struct node* n1;
  struct node* n2;
  root = insert(root, 2);
  root = insert(root, 1);
  root = insert(root, 3);
  print(root);
  return SUCCESS;
}

struct node* insert(struct node* node, int data){
  if(node == NULL){return newnode(data);}
  else{
    if(data < node->data){node->left = insert(node->left, data);}
    else{node->right = insert(node->right, data);}
    return node;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to [debug your small program](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: Hi, My question was more of a conceptual one. `struct node* build123c() {
  struct node* root = NULL;
  root = insert(root, 2);
  root = insert(root, 1);
  root = insert(root, 3);
  return(root);
}` This is a code from stanford's website(link provided in the question). I don't completely understand why this is correct.

Comment: My comment was trying to guide you down the path of, if you want to know why two bits of code are different, break into the debugger at the start of each, step through each line, and see where / why they diverge or do not diverge.

Comment: Conceptually, what is your `insert` function supposed to return? The new node inserted? Or the current root node?

Comment: This comment made me think, I was assuming that the insert function always returns the new node but I was wrong. It returns the new node only when the root node is Null otherwise it returns the new node. Haven't dealt with recursion in a while. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these statements

```
root = insert(root, 2);
root = insert(root, 1);
root = insert(root, 3);
```

`root` continues to point to the same node after the first non-null node pointer is returned from `insert`.

For your expectation to be true, `insert` would have to be defined as something like

```
struct node* insert(struct node* node, int data){
    if (node == NULL) {
        return newnode(data);

    } else {
        if (data < node->data) {
            return ( node->left = insert(node->left, data) );
        } else {
            return ( node->right = insert(node->right, data) );
        }
    }
}
```

But it is not defined that way. (And the tree wouldn't work correctly if it was.) I think the function is simpler than you are making it in your head.

Each node pointer is only returned a single level. When you call `insert(root, ...)`, the return value is either the return value of `newnode` or `root`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the left of the node, then return the left of the node, not the node itself.
If you want to get the right of the node, then return the right of the node, not the node itself.